# Is the fundamenatl quandle of surface-knot a complete invariant up to the mirror images?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

The fundamenatal quandle of classical knots is known to be a complete invariant up to the mirror images. A surface-knot is a closed oriented surface embedded smoothly in 4-space. The fundamental quandle of classical knots can be genralized to surface-knots. my question is: Is the fundamental quandle of surface-knots also a complete invariant for surface-knots up to mirror images?

Comment: Searching for "fundamental quandle surface knot complete invariant" uncovers https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512099 as the second result.  "There exist arbitrarily many inequivalent surface-knots of genus g with the same knot quandle."